# How to rotate text in SVG without transform attribute?

Tags: php, svg, fonts, rotation

I'm using [SVG-Icon-Font-Generator](https://github.com/madeyourday/SVG-Icon-Font-Generator/) to generate a SVG font.

### Unsupported feature

I got input SVG files whom contains both normal text **and** rotated text (90° clockwise) like below:

[image: normal and rotated text in the same SVG file]

When I try to generate my font I got the following error:

```
[Exception]

火-x706B.svg: Transforms are currently not supported!
```

Converting the text to path give the same error.

### Question

Is there a way to rotate a text, and keep it as a  object (for further edit), without using `transform` attribute ? Maybe changing the origin point of the frame.

This will allow me to use the generator.

**N.B.:** I'm using this command to do the conversion:

```
php svg-icon-font-generator.phar create-font ../resources/svg/ ../resources/font/hpf-test.svg
```

Comment: Not sure - can you draw text along a path?

Comment: seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tl;dr

`<svg:text>` and `transform` aren't supported, convert to path.

### From Dev

> Currently you have to convert the text to a path and apply the
>   transform, because transforms and  objects are not
>   supported at this time.
>
> The supported elements are: `path`, `polygon`, `rect`, `circle`, `ellipse`.
>
> Transforms may be supported in the future, but `<svg:text>` would be
>   hard to implement.

[SVG-Icon-Font-Generator/issues](https://github.com/madeyourday/SVG-Icon-Font-Generator/issues/2#issuecomment-23692691)

### How to

You have to **unify both objects into one path** using menu `Path > Union`.

1. Create first text element `火` ;
2. create second text `huō` ;

   1. rotate ;
3. select all and unify path ;
4. Save.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the text along a path instead of using a transform

Comment: the generator manage the file without error, however the output SVG font is all messed up. So I end up converting to path.